# Forward NTP from one network to another network connected to the Internet on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, router

I have NVR server which is running Windows 7 with 2 network interfaces. There is one network dedicated for IP Cameras - 192.168.254/24. Second NIC connected to my network with internet access 192.168.1/23. I would like to sync time on every IP camera via NTP server in the internet. What do I need to configure to allow NTP from 192.168.254/24 network to internet ?

EDIT: Firewall is off

Comment: you may need to allow UDP\123 traffic through your firewall into the .254 network (not leaving it). UDP ports don't play as nicely with NAT as TCP does, so its often necessary to allow it explicitly.

Comment: One way would be to setup the NTP server on the Windows 7 box and have the cameras talk to it, while it in turns syncs with a server out on the internet. The other options are setting up a tunnel, or letting the Windows 7 box act as a gateway, possibly via Internet Connection Sharing